# How does aws latency based routing in route 53 works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, latency, failover

I have two instances one each in Mumbai and North California. I have configured route 53 with the domain name. I want that if someone is coming from India, the request should go to Mumbai server but in case health checks fail they should be routed to North california. I associated two different health checks with both the servers and chose latency based routing but as soon as I stop the service in Mumbai, the request does not goes automatically to North california server although the health checks fail for Mumbai region. Is it supposed to work in this way? I cannot understand it.

Comment: So you setup extra health checks for alias record? Not using the default one?

Comment: One possible reason for this behavior is that DNS clients and resolvers cache DNS responses. Some ignore short TTLs and cache responses for long periods of time. A better solution is to use load balancers where clients enter the network at the closest POP (point of presence). The load balancers make the routing decisions instead of client DNS.

Answer (score 2):

Latency-based routing is separate to failover.

If any health check finds a target to be Unhealthy, then that routing record will be ignored.

When Latency-based routing is configured, requests will go to the lowest-latency target that is Healthy.

Please note that Latency-based routing might take few minutes to affect traffic because DNS requests are cached. A user who previously received a DNS response will need to wait until their cached record expires and the DNS Name is again resolved. A new user, however, will go immediately to the correct destination since they do not have a cached record.